# SQL Query solutions needed for below scenarios?

Tags: sql

**First problem**

```
Table 1 : Id, projectid, Employee name
Table 2 : Id, Salary
```

- Find out the Highest salary for the employee
- Find out the Highest Salary for the Employee in the particular Project.

**Second problem**

```
Table 1: Id,Projectid,Capacity1
Table 2: id,Projectid,Capacity1,Capacity2
```

- if the Capacity2 is null, the value of the Capacity 1 to be Copied to Capacity2.

Comment: So what have you tried ? What problems did you face ?

Comment: Homework... Do you think you'll learn anything if we do it for you?

Comment: Sounds like homework! 1) Look into how to JOIN two tables and perform an aggregate query using GROUP BY and MAX. 2) Not even sure you need to access both tables based on what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

Since I know this is homework because I've seen those questions when I just started, here are some leads for you to read and think about:

1. Check what aggregate functions mean and how to use them.
2. check what is the result of joining the tables.
3. read about SQL NULL Functions.

Good luck!